# FCM differences between Android and iOS about data messages

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send data payload and display notification in my Android and iOS apps. I'm integrating this in my iOS app and I'm in front of a curious thing.

- Short story:

My notification server only send data messages (I mean JSON messages containing "data" field and with no "notification" field). In my Android app this is not a problem because I receive the message even if my app is in background in my `Service` implementation and I manually build a notification that I display. But in iOS case, how can I receive message when my app is in background to do the same? I mean if I add a "notification" field to my request I see the notification pop on my screen (when app is in background) and I can get data (located in the "data" field) after a click when my app is in foreground.

**But can I have data when my app is in the background to manually display a notification?**

- Important precision:

The content of the displayed notification should be built app side and not server side because the server doesn't have enough informations, this is why I can't send the "notification" field in my payload message.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I solve (in part) this problem using [**this link**](https://medium.com/posts-from-emmerge/ios-push-notification-background-fetch-demystified-7090358bb66e#.pvc37icrt). Shortly, I enabled both *Background fetch* and *Remote notifications* under *Background Modes* (and added `content_available : true` in the payload). Then I can process data received in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` But now it still one thing: how make it works when my app is killed?

**EDIT 2:** I found something that could be the thing : [**that**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1). Modifying the payload of a remote notification implies to handle incoming notifications before there are displayed. I'll try.

**EDIT 3:** Firebase doesn't support the *mutable-content* key required to make my solution found at *EDIT 2* working. Discussion about that is [**here**](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/70). So... Any idea?

Comment: Hi FCM now does support the mutable-content key. If you set the mutable_content field in your FCM request to true. You will be able to intercept notification messages before they are presented to the user on iOS 10+.

Comment: Thanks for your work and for information. But why do this release took so long (since iOS10 release)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 16/02/14, Firebase added compliance with the "mutable-content" key. So that solved my problem and, I think, many people's problems.

**Personal thinking:**

I consider that 6 months late for this feature is really too much. I hope that future releases'll be up to date with iOS (as well as Android) releases.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to trigger "stock" notification on iOS from code the same way you do on Android using NotificationBuilder.

The only option available is to use hybrid messages with both notification and data payloads.

Check their [doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options) for more information on hybrid messages.

Comment: Actually, the problem with hybrid messages is that displayed notification is built server side. I want it to be built client (app) side...

Comment: I edited my post. It still one case where it doesn't work : when my app is killed (out of memory)